# ddslick submit onSelected didn't work

Tags: jquery, submit

i used ddslick plugin for a dropdown menu,i tried to submit the form on changing the option but it didn't work,what's wrong with code

```
$('#sel_author').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
        $(function() {
            $("#sel_author").change(function() {
                this.submit();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

i tried this also:

```
$('#sel_author').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
```

plugin source: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $(this).submit()?

or the id of the form eg $('#myform').submit()

Updated:

It looks like you need to wait for the page to be ready first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sel_author').ddslick({
        onSelected: function(selectedData){
            //callback function: do something with selectedData;
            if (jQuery.isReady) {
              $("#formid").submit();
            }

        }
    });
})
```

Comment: yes,but using the id or $(this) make the submit occurs once the page load without changing the option and the submit event occurs multiple times .....so,this doesn't solve the problem